# EXCEL VBA Select Case error checking

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to do an error checking like in the code section below. However, I do not know how to do it properly. Please provide some guidance. Thanks in advance.

```
Select Case Trim(y)
    Case Is = ""
        MsgBox ("Empty field!")

    Case (UCase(Left(y, 1)) = "=") '<--This line requires guidance
        MsgBox ("invalid input")
End Select
```

Comment: If your trying to find out if a cell has a formula use `y.hasformula` will tell you this. Unless your looking at the results of an input box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this won't compile. rather try

```
Select Case UCase(Left(Trim(y), 1))
    Case ""
        MsgBox ("Empty field!")

    Case "="
        MsgBox ("invalid input")
End Select
```

there are alternatives on how to structure your `select` or whether to use it at all (you could opt for cascading `if` statements, for example):

```
Select Case Left(y,1)
    Case "="
        MsgBox ("invalid input")

    Case Else
        If Trim(y) = "" Then
           MsgBox ("Empty field!")
        End If
End Select
```

Comment: I need to check this condition -> (UCase(Left(y, 1)) = "=")

Comment: so why don't you use `if Left(y,1) = "=" then ...` ?

Comment: + 1 2nd one is the way to go :)